Toggling between showing and hiding password on Blazor
I am wondering if it would be possible to create a toggle on an password input field to give the user the ability to toggle between the password being hidden or shown, without using a JavaScript interop.
What I'm trying at the moment is binding a checkbox to a property and set the visibility of the password based on that check being true or false.
@page "/Test"

<div class="form-floating mb-3">
    <input @bind="Input.Password" class="form-control" autocomplete="current-password" aria-required="true" placeholder="password" type="@(ShowPassword ? "text" : "password")" />
    <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
    <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.Password" class="text-danger" />
</div>
<div class="form-check mb-3">
    <input type="checkbox" @bind="ShowPassword" class="form-check-input" />
    <label class="form-check-label" for="showPassword">Show Password</label>
</div>

@code {

    private bool ShowPassword { get; set; } = false;

    private sealed class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; } = "";
    }
}

I'm trying to use data binding instead of the interop, I understand the @bind directive already sets a onchange event, what am I missing here?

Your code is working just fine..  https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/weOymsEF103cbGLS23 Or I need more explanation what are you trying to achieve..

It should...But I can't seem to get it working. I'm doing this on the login supplied by .NET auth identity.

Then there is something you are not showing. What type of interactivity you use? Isn't that just ssr? In that case it wouldn't work for lack of interactivity

@Alamakanambra Yes, I'm using Blazor Server, .NET 8, I do believe it is all server side rendering and that's throwing me off, I'm finding it difficult to find docu on it too.

From the comments it seems you are using just server side rendering, thus no interactivity.
Just place this in your razor file and it should be working.
@rendermode InteractiveServer


I have tried setting the modified login page to rendermode using @rendermode InteractiveServer, however that prevents the login page from loading.
To attempt fixing this I set the  on App.razor to rendermode too, which made the login page load but keep on refreshing constantly.
Then I tried to create a shared component to only load the password input and its checkbox but that would butcher the in-built SignIn authentication on the login page.
